# Limiting number of statements in a SQL query in JDBC

Tags: sql, security, jdbc

Is it possible to do this at all with JDBC?

To emphasise this more, consider the following query which is common in SQL injection:

```
statement.execute("select * from x; drop table y;");
```

Is there a workaround to execute only the first statement here? 
This is possible in some of the NoSQL databases.

Comment: Most drivers won't even allow this, they only support a single statement to be executed at once.

Comment: @RajeevSampath . . . If you want to avoid SQL injection, then use parameterized queries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff unfortunately that's not possible here since I'm dynamically generating a query... (with predicate having variable number of conditions)